# Import script file in react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to break up an template HTML/CSS/JavaScript to work as a React Blog application

When I try to insert the script below, it works fine the first time but when I refresh the page it goes blank.
Same result with importing it in my Header.jsx file.

When I try to use Helmet or useEffect, nothing happens when I click the hamburger menu.
No effect when inserting it as a script in the index.html file either.

Anyone with much more experience and skills than me who knows how I can import av.jsthe script correctly?

The tutorial I am trying to convert to a functional react/mysql blog is for reference
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftJTlsywxFg&t=188s

```js
**Nav.js**

`
    const addEventOnElem = function (elem, type, callback){
    if(elem.length>1){
    for(let i = 0;i<elem.length;i++){
    elem[i].addEventListener(type, callback);
    }
    }else{
    elem.addEventListener(type,callback);
    }
    }

/*
* navbar toggle
*/

    const navbar = document.querySelector("[data-navbar]");
    const navbarLinks = document.querySelectorAll("[data-nav-link]")
    const navToggler = document.querySelector("[data-nav-toggler]");

    const toggleNavbar = function(){
    navbar.classList.toggle("active");
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    }
    addEventOnElem(navToggler, "click", toggleNavbar);

    const closeNavbar = function(){
    navbar.classList.remove("active");
    navToggler.classList.remove("active");
}
addEventOnElem(navbarLinks, "click", closeNavbar);
```

**App.js**

```
import './app.css';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import{Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import{Helmet} from 'react-helmet'
import {ToastContainer} from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import Detail from './pages/Detail';
import AddEditBlog from "./pages/AddEditBlog";
import About from "./pages/About";
import NotFound from "./pages/NotFound";
import Header from './components/Header';

function App() {
  <>
        <Helmet>
        <script
          src="./components/Nav.js">
        </script>
      </Helmet>
  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <Header/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route path="/detail/:id" element={<Detail />}/>
        <Route path="/create" element={<AddEditBlog />}/>
        <Route path="/update/:id" element={<AddEditBlog />}/>
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />}/>
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound/>}/>
      </Routes>
    </div>

  );
  </>
}


export default App;
```

what I tried

import `'./Nav.js'` in both `Header.jsx` and `App.js` (works when saving code) refreshing page makes it go blank.

When using useEffect and Helmet nothing happens when clicking burger menu button

Same result with adding it to the index.html file

Comment: Wrap your helmet comp code inside the app div & then try ?

Comment: Nope did not help. If I do this the script doesn't seem to work. I get it to work by importing the nav.js in app.js. but refreshing the page makes the whole app blank.

Comment: Show the content of file ./components/Nav.js